# File upload function return Exception in laravel API

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-passport

I am developing an API for mobile application. in what API i am creating API for register user. for that i have use passport to create access token for new user. while i am trying to upload profile image using below code I got error message like "ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in file". My code is

```
$files = $request->file('photo');
$filename = str_random() . '.' . $files->extension();
$files->move(public_path() . '/images/user_profiles/', $filename);
```

If i comment that code then everything works fine. I have also try to reinstall passport using below code

```
php artisan passport:install --force
```

but still same error i am getting. can anyone guide me on this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post your request you are making to api any screen shot will be helpful

Comment: and also try this:
$request->file('photo')->storeAs('public/images/user_profiles',$request->photo->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$extension);

Comment: You mean to post postman screenshot?

Comment: yup.
postman screen shot

Comment: screenshot of your headers info as well

Comment: but for register i don't think so i have to pass anything in header.

Comment: you have to pass Content-Type:  multipart/form-data in the  header and also Accept: application/json

Comment: I have upload 2 images and also set header as multipart/form-data in header. but still same error occur. error is showing in passport access token code. but issue in file uploading not in passport access token creation.

Comment: i guess you have added middleware auth:api for this  api route as well right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177014/discussion-between-adarsh-bhatt-and-salman-zafar).